# Manage sqlite3 db not using the official sqlite3 library

Tags: c++, stl, sqlite

I need to simply manipulate a Sqlite3 database (just read some column) and being this just a small part of my program,I don't feel to add 160k line for just few instruction.
There is a way to do this STL or another library that isn't so much memory expensive? 
I Use Visual C++,on Windows.

Comment: Assuming you're on Linux, why not install it via your package manager and link it as a normal library?

Comment: Why in the world someone thumbed down my question?

Comment: I want to note that desktop windows might be the only OS that currently doesn't include sqlite in the default installation.  Everywhere else (server, desktop, mobile, even many embedded), it's already there, so it's no extra cost.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Adding `sqlite3.c` to the project [is the recommended way to use the SQLite library](http://www.sqlite.org/howtocompile.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I could come up with now is to check if you could do the manipulation on the sqlite file on yourself. You can have a look at the file documentation here: https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html

But I don't think that its worth it doing all that on your own.

Another suggestion is this here:
https://www.sqlite.org/footprint.html
You can compile sqlite on your own and omit some of the function it provides, which would make the library smaller. Just compile the functions you need.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,but also compiling the Sqlite3 lib with the strictest option would mean to add tens of thousand of line of code of the library for just few lines in my code.
Trying to do something as a manipulation of the sqlite3 file would be way too time expensive.

Comment: What is time expensive on setting some flags and then compile the library. this should be done in lets say half an hour for a minimal library. The purpose of a library is to bundle functions, of course you only have a few lines of code in your program. Thats what the lib is for. What you want is 10 lines of code for a database functionality...

Comment: Sorry,i misunderstood what you said before. Where i pass the sqlite3 option(The -SQLITE_OMIT_*)? i'm compiling with cl.exe and lib.exe from the VS 2013 tools set

Comment: You need to look how to pass defines with vs. In GCC it would be -D.